# Running gulp-mocha with mongoose Timeout with missing schema error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, gulp, gulp-mocha

After updating *gulp-mocha* to latest version *6.0.0* all my tests crashed.
*mongoose* is complaining with MissingSchemaError, all the tests Timeout even after increasing the timer, I cant find whats wrong. It appears setting up *Mocha* and *Mongoose* has changed and cant find any resource, I tried with promises/ sync and nothing here is how my old code that worked in gulp-mocha :3.0.1 looked

```
gulp.task('mocha', () => {
  process.env.NODE_CONFIG_DIR = './server/tools/config';
  let config = require('configuration')();
  const mongooseTools = require("./server/tools/mongoose-tools");

  return mongooseTools.connect(config.db)
    .then(db => mongooseTools.dropDatabase(db))
    .then(() => Promise.all([
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => gulp.src(testSuites, {read: false})
        .pipe(plugins.mocha({
          reporter: 'spec',
          exit: true,
          checkLeaks: true,
          timeout: 10000
        }))
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('end', resolve))
    ]))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(() => mongooseTools.disconnect());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new [mongoose connection every time](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections). So `mongoose.createConnection().then(conn => {})` instead of `mongooseTools.connect(config.db).then()`. Using the mongoose global connection is messy if you're using something like gulp tasks that re-run continuously.

Comment: I want to start and close the DB in the task not in the tests, saves me from  repetitive code and I can always clear DB in the tests so no mess, also the most important reason Webstorm will fail to stop at debug break points if I run db in tests a bug in their IDE